# why can't i push my radio buttons in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

i'm trying to make a survey in VUEJS I use bootstrap vue to make it better si i tried to make a caroussel to show 1 question once by one could you please tell me why i can select radio in my first caroussel's page but not on the other
i tried to add names and tags which means that there are radio groups but none of these worked

```
<template class="bg-light">
  <b-col offset-lg="3" lg="6" sm="12">
    <b-form>
      <b-carousel
        id="carousel-1"
        v-model="slide"
        :interval="0"
        controls
        indicators
        background="#ababab"
        min-height="500px"
      >
        <b-carousel-slide v-for="q in questions" v-bind:key="q.questionid" >
          <template v-slot:img>
            <b-card class="border-warning bg-dark text-light" style="min-height: 500px">
              <b-card-header class="bg-warning text-dark">{{q.question}}</b-card-header>
              <b-card-body>
                <b-form-radio-group->
                  <br/>
                  <b-radio :id="q.rep1.id" :name="q.questionid" :value="q.rep1.id"><label :for="q.rep1.id">{{q.rep1.text}}</label></b-radio><br/><br/><br/>
                  <b-radio :id="q.rep2.id" :name="q.questionid" :value="q.rep2.id"><label :for="q.rep2.id">{{q.rep2.text}}</label></b-radio><br/><br/><br/>
                  <b-radio :id="q.rep3.id" :name="q.questionid" :value="q.rep3.id"><label :for="q.rep3.id">{{q.rep3.text}}</label></b-radio><br/><br/><br/>
                  <b-radio :id="q.rep4.id" :name="q.questionid" :value="q.rep4.id"><label :for="q.rep4.id"> {{q.rep4.text}} </label> </b-radio><br/><br/><br/>
                </b-form-radio-group-><br/>
              </b-card-body>
            </b-card>
          </template>
        </b-carousel-slide>
      </b-carousel>
      <b-button type="submit" variant="info" @click="calcres">Finir le questionnaire</b-button>
    </b-form>
  </b-col>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Question',
  props: {
    questions: Array
  },
  methods: {
    calcres: function () {
      var idUpadte = this.$route.params.idUpdate
      this.$db.get(idUpadte)
        .then(doc => {
          this.$db.put({
            _id: 'test',
            _rev: doc._rev
          })
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (err.message === 'missing') {
            this.$db.put({
              _id: 'test'
              // ajout resultat
            })
              .then(() => {
                alert('Vos réponses ont été enregistrées')
              })
              .catch(() => {
                alert("Erreur lors de l'envoi des réponses")
              })
          }
        })
    }
  }
}

</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Comment: You don't have a `v-model` or equivalent on the `b-radio` components so it doesn't know where to store the currently selected value.

Comment: yes but when i put a v-model inside my tag it hides my carousel

Comment: That suggests that rendering failed. Without knowing exactly what code you wrote or what errors you saw it's difficult to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: `<b-form-radio-group>` (note: do not add a trailing `-` to the tag name) needs a `v-model` (each card should have it's own v-model) to store the selected value. Also you do not need to add a `<label>` in the content of each `<b-form-radio>`, as it will place the default slot content inside a `<label>` for you automatically (you are getting nested labels in your current markup). Also place `:name="q.questionid"` on the `<b-form-radio-group>` not the individual radios